How to make a bill counter using cv2?
I'm trying to make a bill counter based on their color using Python and cv2, it sometimes works fine detecting the bill's color, but it detects a bill as if it were 2 or even 5, because the color repeats more than once inside the bill, and sometimes it doesn't detect them at all due to the color I put. How can I improve both the detection and that it only counts one time per bill?
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time

#=========================================================================

bill_colors = {
    (67, 86, 101): '20pesos',
    (140, 58, 51): '50pesos',
    (150, 128, 119): '100pesos'
}

def ContourCalculate(image):
    hsvImg = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    detected_bills = set()
    bill_counts = {bill_type: 0 for bill_type in bill_colors.values()}

    for color, bill_type in bill_colors.items():
        for color_range in get_color_ranges(color):
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsvImg, np.array(color_range[0]), np.array(color_range[1]))
            contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

            for contour in contours:
                area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
                if area > 1600:
                    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                    bill_box = (x, y, x + w, y + h)
                    if all(bill_box[i] not in detected_bills for i in range(4)):
                        detected_bills.update(range(x, x + w))
                        bill_counts[bill_type] += 1

    return bill_counts

def get_color_ranges(color):
    # Define multiple color ranges for each bill type
    ranges = []
    ranges.append((np.array(color) - np.array([10, 50, 50]), np.array(color) + np.array([10, 50, 50])))
    ranges.append((np.array(color) - np.array([20, 100, 100]), np.array(color) + np.array([20, 100, 100])))
    ranges.append((np.array(color) - np.array([30, 150, 150]), np.array(color) + np.array([30, 150, 150])))
    return ranges

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    imgS = img.copy()
    
    # Check if 2 seconds have passed
    if time.time() - start_time >= 2:
        bill_counts = ContourCalculate(imgS)
        for bill_type, count in bill_counts.items():
            print(f'{bill_type}: {count}')
        start_time = time.time()  # Reset the timer
    
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

the bills I'm using are Mexican bills and are these: 

Find the rectangle with the bill denomination.  Either read the denomination with pytesseract or use the color there to map to the denomination.

object detection. use AI for best results.
